# How to publish ASP.NET Mvc project by version number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish

Let's say I've finished my project, but I want to publish it on subdirectory of my domain by version number.

Like,

```
http://www.mydomain.com/v1 - first version
http://www.mydomain.com/v2 - second version
http://www.mydomain.com/v3 - third version
```

.....

Is it possible to handle this versioning on IIS or should I use routing?

Comment: u using TFS or any other code management tool?

Comment: Nope, I'm newbie about .NET, never used TFS or any other code m. tool. I'm just trying to get understand mechanism.

Comment: okay. No issues. We had a similar situation. We were using TFS. What i had to do was branch out the versions we wanted to publish and then put them on different subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it differently :

```
 v1.mydomain.com
 v2.mydomain.com
```

And for hosting multiple websites on the same server, you can use this :

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b77cf015-017f-489c-9b5b-65ca4a679392.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: This is not a directly answer to my question but I like this method. This would be more useful. Thanks for suggestion.